# Zero-sized print margins in Excel

Tags: excel, printing

Lets assume that for some reason I want to draw a beautiful orange rectangle that fills the whole page without margins. I set up my page like this: 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxcHA.png)

set all my margins to 0: 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUFfX.png)

and obviously get this beautiful picture in Ctrl+P menu: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl2oz.png)

Unless I launch this file on some other machine that only lets me do something like this: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLeDE.png) *(that's not exactly the image from the other machine, but it looks like this)*.

See those white margins? I can't get rid of them. Excel tells me that all margins are set to 0 and I can't change rows/columns size to remove those white lines.

I would much appreciate any help on this matter. Excel version are the same. The only difference I can think of - I have no printer drivers (because I have no printer) and the other machine has some printers installed. Can the problem be with printer drivers? I checked their options and didn't find anything related to margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with printer after all. Changing printer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Page Size exactly as your output page. May be you are using Letter Page size in Excel but having physically A4 size.